# Getting unhandled rejection(TypeError): cannot read property 'AED' of unrefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i have used the below code in currency converter

```
useEffect(() => {
       if(fromCurrency !=null && toCurrency !=null){
           fetch(`${BASE_URL}?base=${fromCurrency}&symbols=${toCurrency}`)       
                 .then(res => res.json())
               .then(data => setExchangeRate(data.rates[toCurrency]))
       }
     },[fromCurrency,toCurrency])
```

but when i use this i was getting "getting unhandled rejection(TypeError): cannot read property 'AED' of unrefined" error .
i have written this code for ,
when i change the option(dropdown) form eur to another currency then i should get the corresponding values but it didn't.
any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: can you show how the data looks like ?

Comment: `AED` is used in the backend code?

Comment: Please add full code here, where is AED derived?

Comment: here is AED is the currency of the uae country

Comment: when i take off that code it works

Comment: that code is to select the different currencies in the drop down box

Comment: i cannot add full code here